# How to use if condition from using the console output?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

How to use if condition from using the console output?

```
let myURL = URL(string: "http://www.digi.com/laravel_api_demo/api/demoapipost")


let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: myURL!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let postString = "username=rahul"
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in

    guard let _: Data = data, let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else {
        print("error")
        return
    }

    if let dataString = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
    {
        print(dataString)
    }
}
task.resume()
```

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFB4W.png)

How to use this output {"status":"No"} 
I want to use if condition using status value.

Example:

```
if status == "YES"
{
   print("Entered")
}
else
{
   print("Not Entered")
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question but important: unwrapping optionals and discarding them *then* force-unwrapping them again is ridiculously inefficient. Do not do `guard let _: Data = data` and then later `data!`. Instead, unwrap to a variable and use it.

Comment: Unrelated but please don't do that: *`encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)`*. That's weird. Just write `encoding: .utf8`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [parsing invalid JSON Swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46488675/parsing-invalid-json-swift-4)

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your String to Dictionary format.

```
func convertToDictionary(from text: String) -> [String: String]? {
   guard let data = text.data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
   let anyResult = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
   return anyResult as? [String: String]
}

let string1 = "{\"status\":\"No\"}"
let dictionary1 : [String : String] = convertToDictionary(from: string1)!

if dictionary1["status"] == "No"
{
   print("No")
}
else
{
   print("yes")
}
```

As per, @moritz suggestion, you having `JSON Data`, so instead of converting to `String`, you can directly convert your `data` to `[String : String]`

```
if let respJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String : String]
{
    if respJSON["status"] == "No"
    {
       print("No")
    }
    else
    {
       print("yes")
    }
}
```

Comment: They already have the JSON data, so they don't need to first convert it to a string before making an object from it. They should just convert the data to an object, no need to use a string, this is redundant and unnecessary.

Comment: Yes I know, they having JSON Data. I am just answering for their Question.